# Trigger, which logs/deletes a row into a separate table, before an entry with the same attribute value is inserted

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, triggers

I have two tables which both have the same columns and a foreign key named `id`. Table `t1` is supposed to store the current data while table `t2` is a log table.

The rows in table `t1` are supposed to be unique, so I want to create a trigger which copies the data from `t1` to `t2` and then removes the entries in `t1` (if I insert data with an id which is already found in `t1`).

If the id is not found in `t1`, the trigger is simply supposed to insert the data into `t1` and do nothing with `t2`. I am using PostgreSQL and this is my current attempt but it doesn't seem to work:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION move_data_to_historical_measured_data_insert()
    RETURNS TRIGGER
    LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
    AS
$$
BEGIN
    IF OLD.id = NEW.id THEN  
        INSERT INTO t2(id, value, timestamp)
        VALUES(OLD.id, OLD.value, OLD.timestamp);
        DELETE FROM t1;
        RETURN NULL;
    ELSE
        RETURN NULL;
    END IF; 
END;
$$ 
    
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER store_data_to_history_insert
    BEFORE INSERT 
    ON t1
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE move_data_to_historical_measured_data_insert();
```

Comment: OLD is empty on an INSERT, it's NULL. The other issue is RETURN  NULL, return nothing. Any INSERT that should INSERT some data after this trigger fired, has nothing to INSERT, you just returned NULL.

Comment: So i can't make a comparison like: OLD.id = NEW.id, because OLD.id is always NULL? Is my problem solvable with triggers or is my approach completely wrong? I am pretty new to postgresql and triggers and this was the first idea i had

Comment: Use `ON CONFLICT` as explained here [INSERT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html) to `UPDATE` the row if the `id` conflicts. Then use a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger to do the `NEW/OLD` comparison, insert the `OLD` values in the log table and `RETURN NEW` to `t1`.

Comment: Caution: Not directly related, but you should avoid using timestamp as a `column` name. Timestamp is a Postgres data type. While you can use it as a column name it enviably leads to confusion. Best to avoid a `column`  name, or any other database object name,  that is the same as a data type;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION move_data_to_historical_measured_data_insert()
RETURNS trigger
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
begin
    
    if (exists(select t1.id from t1 where t1.id = new.id)) then 
    
        insert into t2 (id, value, timestamp)
        select t1.id, t1.value, t1.timestamp from t1 where t1.id = new.id;
    
        delete from t1 where t1.id = new.id;
    
    end if; 
    
    return new;
END;
$function$
;



CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER store_data_to_history_insert
    BEFORE INSERT 
    ON t1
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE move_data_to_historical_measured_data_insert();
```